# derive a parabola from two tangent lines

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have two tangents of a parabola, one representing initial speed (y=mx) and the other the maximum permissible extent (y=e), and I want to find the gentlest deceleration required to stop in time.  It should be simple but my basic math classes seem to have atrophied...

Or alternatively, if you happen to know control theory, what I'm trying to do is implement soft stops for the various DOFs of a robot, subject to minimally violating the acceleration limits.  If my approach of taking the min of the current speed and the parabola I'm asking about above isn't the right approach, I'm certainly open to better suggestions.

Edit: I also know the X coordinate where mx is tangent to the parabola

Edit 2: I've been working on this in meatspace as well and I think I may have it solved, can one of you check me on this (especially the third equation)?

We have three equations and three unknowns:

$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$m=2ax+b$$
$$e=\frac{-(b^2-4ac)}{4a}$$

and WLOG we'll say that the point at which we know the tangent is $(0, 0)$.  So we solve for $b$:

$$b = m-2ax$$

which leaves us with:
$$y=ax^2+x(m-2ax)+c$$
$$e=\frac{-((m-2ax)^2-4ac)}{4a}$$

then we solve for $c$:
$$c=\frac{-4ae-(m-2ax)^2}{-4a}=\frac{4ae+(m-2ax)^2}{4a}$$
which leaves us with:
$$y=ax^2+x(m-2ax)+\frac{4ae+(m-2ax)^2}{4a}$$
which we can solve for $a$ by plugging in $(0,0)$:
$$a = \frac{-m^2}{4e}$$

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the parabola will have the form

$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$

We have to solve for three constants. Our first constraint is that at some point $x_0$, the fist derivative of the parabola is $m$, or

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{x=x_0}=2ax_0+b=m$$

Solving this gives us

$$a=\frac{m-b}{2x_0}$$

(Assuming $x_0\neq0$) Our other condition is that the maximum of the parabola is equal to $e$. Since we know that the maximum occurs at $x=-b/(2a)$, we know

$$\frac{ab^2}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{2a}+c=-\frac{b^2}{4a}+c=e$$

Observing that in this, case the tangent line is given as $y=mx$, we know that the parabola runs through the origin, thus $c=0$, and $x_0=0$, so $b=m$. This gives us the parabola

$$y=\frac{-m^2}{4e}x^2+mx$$

Your answer is correct.

Comment: Math without context was never my specialty, so I'm thinking about it as physics, the $a$ term is gravity, $b$ is the vertical speed you toss a ball and $c$ is how high you toss it from, right?  So why doesn't $b=m$?
<br>
The trick is that accelerating a DOF costs current, and if the current goes too high the robot burns, so I want it to be as gentle (lowest $|a|$) as possible.  That's why I think the problem is sufficiently constrained (but perhaps I've forgotten to mention some constraint).

Comment: Using the above relations, and setting $x_0=0$, the parabola $y=-m^2/(4(e-c))x^2+mx+c$ will have slope $m$ at $0$, and will have a maximum value $e$ for any value of $c$. These are your only constraints as I understand it. You are right that $c$ is "how high you toss it from, but in this case, you do not know $c$. If you did, that would be the last constraint.

Comment: Upon more carefully reading the question, I realize that if the tangent line at $x=0$ is $y=mx$, then you know that the tangent line has y-intercept $0$, and therefore $c=0$ and the parabola is $y=-m^2/(4e)x^2+mx$

Comment: Good point.  Is the solution I proposed in my question equivalent to your suggestion of setting $c=0$ and solving?  Edit: just saw your comment, so I take it then that the two are equivalent?

Comment: Yes they are. I hope that works for you.

Comment: It will.  If you amend your solution to spare future readers reading the comments I'll happily flag you as the accepted answer.